# how to keep a web worker self-contained

Tags: javascript, constructor, web-worker, worker, self-contained

I built a website that relies on frequently requesting and displaying data from a rest-api using `fetch()`.

After I was done with the hardest part of the work I found that my site doesn't refresh like intended on my iPhone.

First I thought the reason is that Safari on iOS doesn't support `setInterval()` which I used (which seemingly isn't the case).

On my search for an alternative to `setInterval()` I soon came across "web workers". Using the above code I built my 'own' interval which works fine on every device I tested it on:

**main script**:

```
if (typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
   let w = new Worker("webworker.js");

   w.addEventListener("message", () => {
      // my functionality here

      w.postMessage("message");
   });

   w.postMessage("message");
}
```

**webworker.js**:

```
self.onmessage = (msg) => setTimeout(() => self.postMessage("message"), 5000);
```

---

Basically I'm fine with that code, but what I'd like to accomplish is to get rid of the dependence to another file (in this case "webworker.js").

I think an ideal solution would be to pass a function to the constructor of the `Worker`:

```
let w = new Worker((msg) => {
   self.onmessage = (msg) => {
      setTimeout(() => self.postMessage("message"), 5000)
   }
});
```

But as the constructor of the `Worker` class requires an url, I don't see a way to get around this.

Does anyone know another class like `Worker` that would do exactly that or another elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: *I found that devices like the iPhone do not support setInterval()* - this is not true, every browser supports `setInterval`

Comment: Ok, that's weird as my site works on a Mac but not on the iPhone. Maybe there's something else wrong, but definitely there has to be a difference between how the mobile browser is interpreting the code vs. the desktop browser

Comment: Maybe you should ask about the failing interval instead? According to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval#browser_compatibility) setInterval is widely supported.

Comment: Strange... but still it would be interesting if it's possible somehow to not relate to an external source when using "Worker".

Comment: Google "how to debug iphone safari on mac" so you can check what causes the problem